# Spring boot cron expression, every 2 month

Tags: spring-boot, cron

I wanted to construct a spring cron expression that executes At 23:00:00pm, on first Sunday, every 2 months starting in January, so far I have this
`0 0 23 ? 1/2 SUN` but this one executes At 23:00:00pm, every Sunday, every 2 months starting in January. how can I make it execute only the first Sunday every two months?
`0 0 23 ? 1/2 SUN` next excution dates are as follows

```
Sun Mar 07 23:00:00 UTC 2021
Sun Mar 14 23:00:00 UTC 2021
Sun Mar 21 23:00:00 UTC 2021
Sun Mar 28 23:00:00 UTC 2021
Sun May 02 23:00:00 UTC 2021
Sun May 09 23:00:00 UTC 2021
Sun May 16 23:00:00 UTC 2021
Sun May 23 23:00:00 UTC 2021
Sun May 30 23:00:00 UTC 2021
Sun Jul 04 23:00:00 UTC 2021
```

but what I wanted was

```
Sun Mar 07 23:00:00 UTC 2021
Sun May 02 23:00:00 UTC 2021
Sun Jul 04 23:00:00 UTC 2021
```

how can I improve my expression to get the above result?

Comment: Since this will be attached to a method, could you check within the method if the current day is less than or equal to 7 in which case you should proceed with the logic, otherwise nothing executes?

Comment: @alxbxbx Thank you. I haven't thought of that, that should work. I just thought it could all be done through the corn expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
0 0 23 1-7 1/2 SUN
```

The only part you are missing, is day number in the range 1-7.

Code to verify the schedule:

```
var sundays = CronExpression.parse("0 0 23 1-7 1/2 SUN");
var nextDate = LocalDateTime.now();
var dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, MMM d, yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a");

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    nextDate = sundays.next(nextDate);
    System.out.println(nextDate.format(dateFormatter));
}
```

Will run at:

```
Sun, Mar 7, 2021 at 11:00:00 pm
Sun, May 2, 2021 at 11:00:00 pm
Sun, Jul 4, 2021 at 11:00:00 pm
Sun, Sep 5, 2021 at 11:00:00 pm
Sun, Nov 7, 2021 at 11:00:00 pm
...
```